# "WHERE column IS NOT NULL" with Kohana v3 Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana, kohana-3

Is it possible with Kohana **v3** Query Builder to use the IS NOT NULL operator?

The where($column, $op, $value) method requires all three parameters and even if I specify

```
->where('col', 'IS NOT NULL', '')
```

it builds and invalid query eg.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IS NOT NULL '';
```

Comment: v3 is just fine. and you were so close! All you had to do, was move the NULL to the value argument: `->where('col', 'IS NOT', NULL)`

Comment: Now that v3 has better docs and I've had a chance to get used to it-- I'm enjoying it thoroughly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The operator is not escaped:

```
->where('col', 'IS NOT', NULL)
```

No need to use DB::expr, Kohana already supports what you want.

Answer (score 9):

This works with the ORM module and is a little less typing.

```
->where('col', '!=', NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure (it's 3 AM right now) but `->where('col', '', DB::expr('IS NOT NULL'))` might works.

Comment: GENIUS. You sir, are a saint.

Comment: I think it's better to put the 'IS NOT' as the second argument and the value just being NULL. Just like Gerry answered. Using a DB::expr is nice, but adds unnecessary extra overhead (in this case)

Comment: Yeah the best solution is ->where('col', 'IS NOT', NULL)

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause takes 3 arguments, the 1st and 3rd which are always attempted to be converted to the backticks format (i.e. `table`.`field`). As long as you supply the DB::Expr on at least the 3rd argument, you can get away with leaving nothing in 1st and 2nd args and the following should work as well:

```
->where('', '', DB::Expr('!isNull(col)'));
```

This is confirmed to work on Kohana 3.2 and above.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
->where('col', '=', NULL);
```

Comment: That's checking of the value is null, OP wanted is not null.